# Ubuntu 22.04.2 top bar disappearing

Tags: gnome, 22.04, suspend, top-bar

Sometimes, when I suspend my pc or log out and then back in, my top bar disappears. Or sometimes it appears but only a very tiny portion of it. I have the 'hide top bar' extension enabled and so when I drag the pointer to the top of the screen, the top bar doesn't appear. Or when it does, it's only because the clickable parts are highlighted like the date and time area or the top right corner which has the wifi and battery details. In the case of the 2nd scenario, the top bar will fully appear when I toggle overview mode. But for the first case where it totally disappears, nothing appears even in overview mode. Not even the clickable parts of the top bar are highlighted.
[Normal view with cursor on the edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mTi7.png)
[Overview mode and still no top bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MI2bh.png)
[The enabled top bar extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqxns.png)(Toggling this on and off doesn't help. Sometimes it resolves itself after logging off and back on again. The only constant solution is when I restart the pc)